# How do I center the table of contents title without using tocloft?

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, titles, titlesec, tocloft

I would simply like to center the title of the table of contents in my "book" document.

I just added dot leaders to the table of contents, and this appeared to be best accomplished by forgoing the `tocloft` package and instead using the `\dottedcontents` command of the `titlesec` companion package, `titletoc`, like so:

```
\dottedcontents{chapter}[0em]{\vspace{2.1ex}}{0em}{0.5pc}
```

Introducing `tocloft` settings in order to center the TOC title causes what appears to be a vertical placement/spacing problem that I'm not sure how to correct (this is described in detail in my comments to Peter's answer below).  I would therefore like to avoid using the `tocloft` package if possible.

One way to approach the centering task would be to add `\centering` to the chapter `\titleformat` command of the `titlesec` package:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\centering\Large\bfseries}{}{}{}
```

However this centers all chapter titles, and I don't want this.

So, my question is:  what is the simplest way to center the table of contents title without affecting other chapter titles and without using `tocloft`?

Here is a near minimal example (with my attempts at using the `tocloft` package omitted):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\Large\bfseries}{}{}{}

\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\dottedcontents{chapter}[0em]{\vspace{2.1ex}}{0em}{0.5pc}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\vspace{24pt}

\chapter*{Left-Justified Chapter 1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Left-Justified Chapter 1}

Some indented text.

\chapter*{Left-Justified Chapter 2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Left-Justified Chapter 2}

More indented text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you use `\section*` for what's supposed to be a chapter?

Comment: Just to allow "chapters" 1 and 2 to appear on the same page as the table of contents while working with the minimal example on my system.  These can be changed to \chapter* for consistency, and I've done so above to avoid confusion.

Comment: By default the `tocloft` package does not change the ToC (or LoF or LoT) layout from that of the standard classes, except that they need not start on new pages. I don't know what you might have done to change these to results you don't like.

Comment: Hi Peter, see my comments under your answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a `\titleformat` within a group, after `\begin{document}`.

Unrelated: with the companion package `titletoc`, you have a much simpler way to format the entries in the table of contents, with the `\dottedcontents` command.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec, titletoc, xcolor}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\Large\bfseries}{}{}{}

\usepackage{indentfirst}

\dottedcontents{chapter}[3.8em]{\vspace{2ex}}{2.3em}{0.8pc}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{\color{red}}{}{}
\tableofcontents
\vspace{24pt}
\endgroup

\chapter*{Left-Justified Chapter 1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Left-Justified Chapter 1}

Some indented text.

\chapter*{Left-Justified Chapter 2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Left-Justified Chapter 2}

More indented text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default the `tocloft` package uses the standard class's (`book`, `report`, `article`) settings for the ToC, LoF and LoT. The following (less any typos) is a solution to your problem using `tocloft`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}

%% center Contents title
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}

%% add dot leaders to chapters
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\end{document}
```

This makes no changes to the indentation and vertical placement of the entries.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the MWE.  For the code you wrote, I find that including the tocloft package and related settings (as opposed to commenting them out) not only centers the title and adds dot leaders, but also raises both the title and entries by about the height of the title.  This upward shift is one example of what I'm calling an unwanted change in vertical placement.

Comment: Additionally, when the TOC is long enough, LaTeX apparently may adjust vertical spacing between entries so that the final entry on the page is a fixed distance from the bottom of the page.  This means that the upward shift that I just described can lead to differences in inter-entry spacing.  Hope this clarifies what I meant.  Thanks for encouraging me to look at this more closely.

Comment: Finally, it turned out that the indentation issue that I mentioned in my original question had another explanation (tocloft was not to blame), and I have edited my question accordingly.  Thanks, Peter.

Comment: @SapereAude When I processed my MWE there was no change in the vertical position of the title or entries. For long (multipage) ToCs LaTeX will alter, or not, the vertical spacing between the entries according as to whether `\raggedbottom` or `\flushbottom` is in effect.

Comment: Interesting.  The upward vertical shift, which on closer inspection appears to be the line width of a TOC entry, is quite reproducible on my end.  In such a minimal example, it was not easy for me to see this difference without printing out the TOC with and without the tocloft lines commented out.  In any event, I've opened a new [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479211/tocloft-appears-to-raise-the-table-of-contents-of-books-what-gives) about this.