# tocloft appears to raise the table of contents of books. What gives?

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, tocloft, books

I would like to use the `tocloft` package for customizing the table of contents in my "book" document.  However, when I include this package, the table of contents shifts upward by the line width of a single TOC entry.  What could be the issue?

The minimal example in this case is surprisingly minimal:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```

A tip for those who don't immediately see a visual difference:  It helps to print out page 1 before and after commenting out `\usepackage{tocloft}` and then place the sheets of paper on top of each other and hold them up to the light.  (I'm serious.)

Comment: The table of contents title is implemented (in book class) using `\chapter*{\contentsname}`.  Not sure what tocloft does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you load the [`tocloft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) without options, it constructs the header of the `\tableofcontents` in a manual fashion that is *similar* to that of the default document classes. This is done so that `tocloft` will cover the setting of ToCs to a broader audience than just the basic classes - it's easier to construct your own way of setting the header/title rather than rely on whatever custom class someone might be using.

If you want to use the default document class' `\tableofcontents`, then you can load `tocloft` with the `titles` option. This leaves the original definition of `\tableofcontents`' header/title in place yet still allows for updating of the formatting.

---

Under the hood, the main difference stems from `book` using `\chapter*` to set `\tableofcontents`, while `tocloft`'s default behaviour is to mimic if via similar `\vspace`s and font selection, but not actually set a `\chapter*`.